# meaning of Netstat local address column

Tags: netstat

When I do `netstat -ntlp` there is a column called `Local Address`:

- sometimes it would output IP address as `0.0.0.0:7180`
- and sometimes `127.0.0.1:9001`

What's the implications of both notations?

Does specific IP address act like a filter for incoming connections? E.g. for `127.0.0.1:9001` it will only accept connections from localhost on port 9001?

Answer (score 20):

I think you've answered your own question.

As an example, `apache` has it's `Listen` option which tells it which address and port to listen on.  Depending on how this is set, `apache` will listen on any IP address, a specific address:-

```
Listen *:80
Listen 0.0.0.0:80
Listen 127.0.0.1:80
Listen 192.168.0.5:80
```

The above options show  up as:-

```
:::80
0.0.0.0:80
127.0.0.1:80
192.168.0.5:80
```

and translate to:-

- Listen on any IP address (IPv4 or IPv6)
- Listen on any IPv4 address on that server
- Listen on IPv4 localhost only
- Listen on external IPv4 address 192.68.0.5

You could configure your service to listen on only the `localhost` interface if you don't want anyone external to access it.  For example, if you're running a LAMP server you'd have `apache` listening on all IP addresses (so that your users can access it) while a `mysql` database could be configured to be accessible only from `localhost` (using it's `bind=127.0.0.1` directive).  This way `php` running on the same server will be able to access the database while external (and untrusted) users will not be able to access it.

Comment: `:::80` does not always imply IPv4 as well https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/496150/333382

Answer (score 16):

#### 127.0.0.1 and 0.0.0.0

`127.0.0.1` means local interface or loopback address. Only accessible from your localhost.

`0.0.0.0` is a wildcard address for every interface.

On `netstat -ntlp` `Local Address` means "Print active listening tcp connections, show IPs as numeric values and show the PID and name of the program that uses this connection."

---

#### Difference by example

E.g. if I have

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name                 
tcp        0      0 127.0.1.1:53            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1189/prog1
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:6666            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1188/prog2
```

that means:

The service `prog1` with PID `1189` listens on port `53` with protocol `tcp`. It is only accessible from your localhost.

The service `prog2` with PID `1189` listens on port `6666` with protocol `tcp`. Access to this port is allowed from any other computer on all networks the computer is part of.

Sources: [1](https://serverfault.com/a/78058/227935) [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18146110/3739455) [3](https://superuser.com/a/240110/333431)

Answer (score 3):

`0.0.0.0` means the process is bound to all interfaces.

`127.0.0.1` means the process is bound only to the `127.0.0.1` interface (loopback).

If you had other interfaces you might have `x.y.z.a` entries indicating the process was bound to those specific interfaces.

A process will only be told if traffic arrives on the interfaces to which it is bound, so yes, it's kind of a filter, although it's not usually described in those terms.

Answer (score 2):

The "local address" is the address to which the socket in question is bound. This is the address which it receives connections on. The addresses you're asking about are "special addresses". According to [the manual page for the Linux IPv4 protocol](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/ip.7.html#DESCRIPTION):

> There are several special addresses: `INADDR_LOOPBACK` (`127.0.0.1`)
>   always refers to the local host via the loopback device; `INADDR_ANY`
>   (`0.0.0.0`) means any address for binding; `INADDR_BROADCAST`
>   (`255.255.255.255`) means any host and has the same effect on bind as
>   `INADDR_ANY` for historical reasons.

What this means for the address `0.0.0.0` is that the socket can receive connections for any address on the system, on any interface.

Answer (score 1):

As you told, the IP of localhost only accept connections to those ports locally while the IP **0.0.0.0** refers to ports that are open to all.

For example

Local

```
127.0.0.1:8307 VMWARE
127.0.0.1:25   MASTER
```

To all

```
0.0.0.0:80    HTTP
0.0.0.0:443   SKYPE
```